# Spring MVC Controller stucked and not responding

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I faced some specific issue:
My rest controller works for some hours, than I do not know why when I make a request to it. It does not respond. Loading process in browser is keeping wait for response for a while. If I send request with a POSTer I can see that request went to controller, but no response received. I tried to debug app, I have some scheduled processed - they are working. But controller not. Request does not reach the controller. It stuck before. How I can find out where this is happening? Thank you. This is my controller class:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/quotes")
public class QuotesController {

private final QuotesService quotesService;

@Autowired
public QuotesController(QuotesService quotesService) {
    this.quotesService = quotesService;
}

@RequestMapping(value="", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<LoadedFileInfo>> getLoadedFilesData(){
    List<LoadedFileInfo> result = quotesService.getLoadedFilesData();
    return new ResponseEntity<List<LoadedFileInfo>>(result, HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/currencyPairs", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<CurrencyPair>> getCurrencyPairs(){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<CurrencyPair>>(quotesService.getCurrencyPairs(), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/oneMinute", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getOneMinuteQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getOneMinuteQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/fiveMinutes", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getFiveMinutesQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getFiveMinuteQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/fifteenMinutes", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getFifteenMinutesQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getFifteenMinuteQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/thirtyMinutes", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getThirtyMinutesQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getThirtyMinuteQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/oneHour", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getOneHourQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getOneHourQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/fourHours", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getFourHourQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getFourHourQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/oneDay", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getOneDayQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getOneDayQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/oneWeek", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getOneWeekQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getOneWeekQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}

@RequestMapping(value="/oneMonth", method= RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json; charset=utf-8")
public ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>> getOneMonthQuotes(@RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime from, @RequestParam @DateTimeFormat(iso= DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) LocalDateTime to, @RequestParam Integer currencyPair){
    return new ResponseEntity<List<Number[]>>(quotesService.getOneMonthQuotes(from, to, currencyPair), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

}

Comment: It is for all controllers or just one ? Do you see any error in the logs ? Have you tried a thread dump ? Have you connected a visualVM on it ? What application server ?

Comment: It is a SpringBoot. I have only one controller. There are no errors in logs. I have not tried thread dump, and did not connect visualVM

Comment: Can you post Controller code which you created for the REST.

Comment: I have a very similar problem. My application works normally, but suddenly some endpoints stop working, returning only 404. There's no output on the logs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is something wrong with your Controller, at least there is not evidence for that in the provided code.
There are a lot of reasons what can go wrong here, to name a few:

- **HTTP Connection Pool is full**
  A web server that runs your application has a connection pool - a number of available HTTP connections.
  Unless you're using an async stuff (I assume you don't), its possible that the pool just becomes overwhelmed with a numerous connections running in parallel and trying to access the controller.

  So first of all check that connection pool is ok, usually connection pools expose some kind of management. For example there is a JMX for that in Tomcat), so log in with jconsole for example and ensure that there are many free connections.
- **There is an occasional network issue**
  This one is really easy to figure out.
  Just add some trace messages at the very beginning of your controller and log them. Then check the log and see whether you see a new message upon each and every request, if you do, the code is called properly.
- **The flaw is inside the application itself**
  In this case you should see that it takes ages for controller method to complete the flow (again, trace with logs at the beginning and at the end of controller method can help). 
  So, to prove this, consider taking a thread dump. There are many ways to do that, for example: if you're on linux, run **kill -3** on your java process, alternatively you can use jstack, so just find what works best for you.
  Anyway, a thread dump should show where does your application gets stuck in a point of time when you take it.
  So if you take it, say twice and still see that the thread responsible for the controller execution is stuck the same place - you're lucky one :)

From that you can profile the application and understand where exactly the time is spend, but this should be done "offline" I believe and not in a production machine.

Sorry if this answer sounds too basic, but since you haven't really tried any type of analysis like that I've assumed that such an explanation can help

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. There are a lot of helpful information. Will try to analyze it and use. Thank you